# Может ли обработчик события возвращать данные?

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

Программирую на AS3.

```
public static function isUserExist (): Boolean
{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://какие-то_буковки);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoad);
    loader.load(request);

    function completeLoad (): Boolean
    {
        if (loader.data != "null") return true;
        else if (loader.data == "null") return false;
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoad);
    }
}
```

Я загружаю данные с сервера и в зависимости от них должен вернуть булевое значение в функцию, которая вызывала метод isUserExist (). Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript 3 не поддерживает синхронную остановку кода. В completeLoad() устанавливайте какой нибудь Boolean флаг и читайте его.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае вам следует подойти к вопросу с использованием своих событий:

```
public function isUserExist():void { //название метода следует изменить
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://какие-то_буковки");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoad);
    loader.load(request);
}

private function completeLoad(e:Event):void {
    if (loader.data) { //Я не уверен, может ли свойство URLLoader#data быть null уже после Event#COMPLETE
        dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.SUCCESSFULL));
    } else {
        dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.FAILED));
    }
}
```

И "снаружи" уже обрабатывать события.

```
var myClass:MyClass = new MyClass();

myClass.addEventListener(MyEvent.SUCCESSFULL, successfullHandler);
myClass.addEventListener(MyEvent.FAIL, failHandler);
myClass.isUserExist();

***

private function successfullHandler(e:MyEvent):void {

}

private function failHandler(e:MyEvent):void {

}
```

Предварительно надо создать новый класс MyEvent, наследуемый от Event. Внимательней отнеситесь к значениям констант, т.к. они могут "пересечься" с уже имеющимися событиями.

```
public class MyEvent extends Event {

    public static const SUCCESSFULL:String = "mySuccessfull";
    public static const FAIL:String = "myFail";

    public function MyEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в конечном итоге я к этому и пришёл.